# Logic behind computing probability.

Tags: probability

I have this question and I solved it in this way. **I have seen the solution, I just want to know why my approach is wrong.**

> An urn contains 10 white and 3 black balls. Another urn contains 3 white and 5 black balls. Two balls are drawn from first urn and put into the second urn and then a ball is drawn from the latter. Find the probability that it is a white ball.

What I did is:

There are three possibilities (i) Both the balls transferred were white.

(ii) One was white one was black.

(iii) Both the balls transferred were black.

Now for the first case, Probability of picking a white ball from the second urn should be: 10/13$*$9/12$*$5/10

(since picking any 10 out of 13 first then 12 balls left out of which 9 white, finally multiplying the probability of picking white ball from the 2nd urn)

Similarly for all three cases I got certain values and added the three together.

But the answer is not matching. Please tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: "*but the answer is not matching*"  You did not share the full computation.  From what you have shown here, it should be a valid approach.

Comment: ok i will post a pic

Comment: Check to make sure the "*one was white one was black*" case you deal both with the possibility of the *first* being white and second being black as well as the possibility of the *second* being white and first being black.

Comment: The basic logic of what you wrote seems fine, so the problem is most likely in the details.

Comment: Thank you so much @JMoravitz I did go wrong in that step. Missed one *2

Comment: Please suggest some nice books on Probability. Everything in my book is formula based. Even in this question they directly applied Baye's theorem